# AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'driver'

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am new to Selenium and I am trying to scrape all the book list info stored in book_list, which will then be showed in pandas dataframe.
Here is the code that's the script I am using :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time

url = "https://book.naver.com/"
query = 'python'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nx_query"]').send_keys(query)
time.sleep(4.5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search_btn"]').click()
time.sleep(4.5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a').click()
time.sleep(4.5)

books = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchBiblioList"]/li[1]/dl')

book_list = []

for book in books:
    title = book.driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="searchBiblioList"]/li[1]/dl/dt/a').text
    desp = book.driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="searchDescrition_17854273"]').text
    book_item = {
    'title' : title,
    'desp' : desp
    }
    
    book_list.append(book_item)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(book_list)
print(df)
```

**This throws an error :**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-f96a3c3baaf4> in <module>()
      4 
      5 for book in books:
----> 6     title = book.driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="searchBiblioList"]/li[1]/dl/dt/a').text
      7     desp = book.driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="searchDescrition_17854273"]').text
      8     book_item = {

AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'driver'
```

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 1):

easy.

this is your `books`:

```py
books = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchBiblioList"]/li[1]/dl')`
```

it has been a driver object generator.

then,you use for loop to get each `book`, it has been the seleium object, so you don't need to use `book.driver`, just use `book.find_element_by_xpath`, just like below:

```py
for book in books:
    title = book.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="searchBiblioList"]/li[1]/dl/dt/a').text
    desp = book.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="searchDescrition_17854273"]').text
    book_item = {
    'title' : title,
    'desp' : desp
    }
```

Hope it's helpful, Goood Luck.